# Do infinite coprime points $(x,y)$ exist satisfying $x+y=n$ where $x,y,n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, coprime

I'm trying to [prove infinite primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem) exist based upon [this](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/PickApps.shtml):
For $n$ prime, every grid point on the line is coprime.

Examples of $x+y=n$ for $n$ prime

```
n=3  {(1,2),(2,1)}
n=5  {(1,4),(2,3),(3,2),(4,1)}
n=7  {(1,6),(2,5),(3,4),(4,3),(5,2),(6,1)}
...
```

Can it be shown there exists infinite such sequences, thus proving infinite primes exist?

Thanks.

Comment: If $p$ is prime and $d$ divides $i$ and $p - i$, then $d$ divides $ i + (p-i) = p$, so $x = i$ and $y = p-i$ are coprime.

Comment: $0$ and $3$ are not coprime since $3$ divides each of them.

Comment: The title suggest $n$ is a generic number from $\mathbb{Z}$. But the examples use $3,5,7$ which are positive, odd, and prime. It leaves me unclear whether you really mean $\mathbb{Z}$ or something smaller.

Comment: Lastly, the way the title question is phrased, it sounds like you are asking for infinitely many solutions for _each_ $n$. But your examples only list finitely many solutions for a few $n$. It's another thing that leaves me wondering what the question really is.

Comment: Changed n from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Also, removed the points with $0$ as you noted $(0,3)$ not coprime. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integers_Coprime_to_Zero 
 I'm learning...Thanks.

Comment: Using Rob Arthan's comment, as there is an infinite number of primes there is an infinite number of such pairs.  I wouldn't know how to prove there is an infinite number of such pairs without using the fact that there is an infinite number of primes.  You would have to carefully define what one was allowed to use.  I suspect you would wind up incorporating a proof that there is an infinite number of primes in the proof that there is an infinite number of such pairs.

Comment: And please try to tighten up the precision of your language. There is no infinite prime, nor infinite coprime point. You meant to ask whether there were *infinitely many* primes or coprime points. Or else to ask whether the *set* of objects with the stated property was infinite.

Comment: I'm trying to prove there are infinite primes (I know there is from Euclid et al) by checking if an infinite number of coprime sequences exist. For example, let $n=7$ gives  ${(1,6),(2,5),(3,4),(4,3),(5,2),(6,1)}$. As usual, I'm great at confusing people. Sorry about that! Please feel free to close or delete. Thanks!

Comment: @alex.jordan: thanks for your reminder. I assumed on the basis of the OP's examples, that $\Bbb{N}$ did not include $0$ in his or her world.

Comment: @RobArthan At the time I wrote the comment, OP's post was different. You can check the edit history of the post.

Comment: @alex.jordan: I see. No hard feelings, I hope.